# All nodes in XML using Linq C#

Tags: c#, .net, linq

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Use LINQ to read all nodes from XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872611/use-linq-to-read-all-nodes-from-xml)

I am trying to read an XML file using Linq in C# windows application. The sample of the xml string is given below.

```
<Root>
<Name>John Doe</Name>
<Data>FBCCF14D504B7B2DBCB5A5BDA75BD93B</Data>
<customer>true</customer>
<Accounts>1</Accounts>
<dataSet>
     <Type1>Found matching records.</Type1>
    <Type2>No matches found.</Type2>
   <Type3>Found matching records.</Type3>
</dataSet>
</Root>
```

I want to display all the data inside the `<dataset>` tag and `<datatag>` i want to read `<customer>` tag as well.

I have created a class with members (string type, string status). Where in type i want to store the type1, 2...and in status i want to store what is inside the type node.

I am able to accomplish this but in the code i have to give

`type1 = (string)row.Element("type1"),
     type2=(string)row.Element("type2"),`

i want to have a generic code in which i dont have to mention every type. In other words i want to read all the child nodes of  tag whithout mentioning the tag name. I have spent 2 hours searching for this on google, but haven't found anything yet.

Expected output

save the information in class object (type and status).

And i want to read the customer tag so that i can know whether the person is already a customer

Any help will be very much appreciated.

Thanks

**Update**

According to inputs received from Raphaël Althaus

I have the following code:

```
var list = xml.Descendants("dataSet").Elements()
            .Select(m => new CustomerInfo
                             {
                                 Type = m.Name.LocalName,
                                 Value = m.Value
                             }).ToList();


        foreach (CustomerInfo item in list)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(item.Type+ "   "+item.Value);

        }
```

and for reading the Customer tag i have written more code.

```
var isCustomer = from customer in xmlDoc.Descendants("Root")
            select new
            {
              customer = tutorial.Element("customer").Value,
            }
```

Can i do both in one query?. Or this method is not so heavy on performance, so i can use this?

Comment: I found partial answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5978926/c-using-linq-to-get-a-ienumerable-collection-of-xml-nodes-to-traverse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like that ?

```
var q = xml.Descendants("dataSet").Elements()
            .Select(m => new
                             {
                                 type = m.Name.LocalName,
                                 value = m.Value
                             }).ToList();
```

You can also directly populate a list of your "class with members"

```
var list = xml.Descendants("dataSet").Elements()
                .Select(m => new <TheNameOfYourClass>
                                 {
                                     Type = m.Name.LocalName,
                                     Value = m.Value
                                 }).ToList();
```

EDIT :

to get the "customer" value, I would do another query

```
var customerElement = xml.Element("customer");
var isCustomer = customerElement != null && customerElement.Value == "true";
```

So you could mix all of that it in a little function

```
public IList<YourClass> ParseCustomers(string xmlPath, out isCustomer) {
    var xml = XElement.Load(xmlPath);
    var customerElement = xml.Element("customer");
    isCustomer = customerElement != null && customerElement.Value == "true";
    return xml.Descendants("dataSet").Elements()
                    .Select(m => new <YourClass>
                                     {
                                         Type = m.Name.LocalName,
                                         Value = m.Value
                                     }).ToList();
}
```

Comment: thanks, it is working but it will return only the elements under dataset. I want <data> tag also. Is there way to do that in one shot?
when i replace xml.Descendants("dataSet") by xml.Descendants("root")>
i get type=Dataset and value=all values under <dataset> tags

Comment: not clear with your initial question : could you please give a list of expected result based on your xml example ?

Comment: Expected Result:
Type and Value in class which is already done.
I want to read <customer> tag as well. So that i can know whether the person is already a customer.

Comment: Just one more precision needed : you can have many persons in your xml, right ? So doesn't your example miss a node ? <Root><Person><Name>JohnDoe</Name>(other tags)</Person><Person>xxx</Person>

Comment: Well no...Actually this output is from a website which gives results according to the customerid and i have to parse that. So it will always return only one record

Comment: ok, edited... Done in 2 part (null check needed)